# Combine multiple rows into single row in a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have these two tables, I will joining using EMP_PHONE_ID to get the results. The JOIN condition is a bit more 
complicated, but this is just a sample to get started. When I JOIN the two tables, I'm getting 2 rows for each EMP_ID
since each EMP_ID maps to two EMP_PHONE_ID. I would like the end results to be single row the combines both PERM and TEMP values.

```
TABLE B 

EMP_PHONE_ID      ||    PERM_VALUE   ||    TEMP_VALUE
1                 ||      value1     ||      NULL 
2                 ||      NULL       ||      value2 
3                 ||      value3     ||      NULL 
4                 ||      NULL       ||      value4 


TABLE A

EMP_ID     ||EMP_PHONE_ID ||CODE
1          ||1            ||1    
1          ||2            ||2   
2          ||3            ||1    
2          ||4            ||2            




DESIRED RESULTS 

EMP_ID      ||    PERM_VALUE   ||    TEMP_VAL
1           ||      value1     ||      value2 
2           ||      value3     ||      value4 

Here's my select 
     SELECT
     CASE WHEN A.CODE = 1 THEN B.PERM_VALUE  END AS PERM_VALUE1,
     ASE WHEN A.CODE = 2 THEN B.PERM_VALUE  END AS PERM_VALUE2
     FROM TABLE A A,  TABLE B B
     WHERE A.EMP_PHONE_ID = B.EMP_PHONE_ID;



DESIRED RESULTS 

EMP_ID      ||    PERM_VALUE   ||    TEMP_VAL
1           ||      value1     ||      value2 
2           ||      value3     ||      value4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Inner join` + `Group By` + `Min or Max` aggregate should work for you

```
SELECT EMP_ID,
       Min(PERM_VALUE) as PERM_VALUE,
       Min(TEMP_VALUE) as TEMP_VALUE
FROM   TABLEA A
       JOIN TABLEB B
         ON A.EMP_PHONE_ID = B.EMP_PHONE_ID
GROUP  BY EMP_ID
```

If you want to display the data based on `Code` then use this

```
SELECT EMP_ID,
       Min(CASE WHEN A.CODE = 1 then PERM_VALUE end) as PERM_VALUE,
       Min(CASE WHEN A.CODE = 2 then TEMP_VALUE end) as TEMP_VALUE
FROM   TABLEA A
       JOIN TABLEB B
         ON A.EMP_PHONE_ID = B.EMP_PHONE_ID
GROUP  BY EMP_ID
```

I think you are storing the data in wrong way in `TABLEA`

Comment: This would work if PERM_VALUE is always MIN and TEMP_VALUE is always MAX, but in my case these values varies and would even match between rows.

Comment: @Mr.Maze - I didnt use `Max` aggregate, I meant `Min` or `Max` aggregate. I just considered there will be always two related rows for each `EMP_ID` in `TABLE A`

Comment: I see. I have refined the tables and the query I'm using to reflect the problem.